# How to solve following system of equations

Tags: math, octave

I've taken a few measurements of an LC circuit and I need to solve for both L and C based on that. How do I solve this?

```
2.675e6 = 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(L * (C + 100e-9))
5.8e6 = 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(L * C))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need pencil and paper:

Equation #1

```
5.8e6 = 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(L * C))
sqrt(L * C)= 1 / (2 * pi * 5.8e6 )
L*C = 1 / (2 * pi * 5.8e6 )^2
```

Equation #2

```
2.675e6 = 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(L * (C + 100e-9))
sqrt(L * (C + 100e-9))= 1 / ( 2 *pi *2.675e6 )
L * (C + 100e-9) = 1 / ( 2 *pi *2.675e6 )^2
```

Subtract #1 from #2

```
L * (C + 100e-9) - L*C = 1 / ( 2 *pi *2.675e6)^2 - 1 / (2 * pi * 5.8e6 )^2 
L * 100e-9 = 1 / ( 2 *pi *2.675e6)^2 - 1 / (2 * pi * 5.8e6 )^2
L = 1e7 * (1 / ( 2 *pi *2.675e6)^2 - 1 / (2 * pi * 5.8e6 )^2 )
```

and than from #1

```
C = ( 1 / (2 * pi * 5.8e6 )^2 ) / L
```